# Slide Menu - any way to programmatically expand it?

Tags: user-interface, smart-device, genexus

My App made in Genexus has a navigation Style = Slide.
When it launches, a login screen pops up. When the login is done and the popup closes, all the user can see is a blank panel.

Is there any way of expanding the menu after the return command of the login panel?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that reported in this SAC (spanish): 
http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxppredirect.aspx?15,26,0,,,36141

Please, read the "workaround" section for a temporary solution. 
Basically it said that, in this case, an output parameter needs to be including when calling the login panel.

Comment: Hello Pablo, that SAC was opened by me :) So, yes, the workaround is already implemented. It would be nice if there was a way of programatically expand a collapsed menu in "Slide" applications. That would solve the problem. If that's not possible i'll try a welcome panel, so the App does not start empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Event 'anyEvent'
  MainMenuPanel.CallOptions.Target = "Left"
  MainMenuPanel.Call()
EndEvent
```

This should work.